# Why does the second aliya of Vayeira start with the last verse of one topic and then change?

Tags: torah-reading, vayera

[The second aliya of Vayeira](http://www.bible.ort.org/books/torahd5.asp?action=displaypage&book=1&chapter=18&verse=15&portion=4) begins at 18:15, with the end of the Sarah-denying-having-laughed episode.  It then goes on to focus on S'dom and the other cities.  This happens in the middle of a column, not near a "paragraph" break of either sort, so the division isn't dictated by those boundaries so far as I can tell.  Nor is 18:15 a "down" note that we wouldn't want to end an aliya on.

So why is 18:15 the first verse of the second aliya and not the last verse of the first one?

Comment: Prompted by the [weekly topic challenge](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/752/weekly-topic-challenge-5772-25-week-of-tzav-5772-book-division), and having leined this and wondered at the time...

Comment: I'm *guessing* it's to end on a high note ("son") rather than a somewhat low note ("you laughed", which was viewed as a bad thing). As it's purely a guess, though, I'm not posting it as an answer.

Comment: As @msh210 posted 31 seconds before me, I dont know the source of offhand, but we try to end Aliyot on a positive note. Instead of ending with a criticism of Sara, we end with a promise for children. Thats my guess at least, but perhaps someone discusses it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ephraim Stulberg, in an interesting article on the subject of the division of Aliyot (available [here](http://www.biu.ac.il/js/JSIJ/8-2009/Stulberg.pdf)), suggests that as an extension of the theme of ending on a good note, the 'divisors' tried to end aliyot with dramatic and uplifting messages as a climax to the aliya. His examples are: [Gen 9:17](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0109.htm#17), [13:4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0113.htm#4), [13:18](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0113.htm#18), [19:20](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0119.htm#20), [28:22](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0128.htm#22), [33:5](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0133.htm#5), [33:20](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0133.htm#20), [42:18](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0142.htm#18), [49:18](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0149.htm#18), [Ex 9:16](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0209.htm#16), [14:8](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0214.htm#8), [Lev 9:23](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0309.htm#23), and [Num 14:7](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0414.htm#7). He lists [Gen 18:14](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0118.htm#14) as a possible member of this category, because it is quite exciting and climactic when Sara first hears she will have a child.

Comment: You should probably provide excerpts from the examples he provides, for passers-by without a text handy. :)

Comment: @Aarthi I can try to do so later on. In my defense, the original author himself only brought an except from one of them (Gen 42:18) and left the others as references.

Comment: Ah! Totally understandable; I mostly meant that from my perspective. As someone with neither reference materials handy, nor a better knowledge of scriptures, I find it hard to judge answers that are more citation than material, you know? Not a slight against you -- a request from an acknowledged gentile. :D

Comment: @Aarthi Done. And remember that you always have reference materials handy: http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0.htm :)

Comment: Wow, how many comments are there from @Aarthi on the content of M.Y. questions and answers?

Comment: @SethJ Just these.