# Torah portions that end abruptly?

Tags: torah-reading, va-eira, shemot-exodus

In parshat Va-era the 2nd portion - Sheini ends rather abruptly (in the middle of a sentence) [Shemot 6:28](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/showrashi/true/aid/9867/jewish/Chapter-6.htm):

> Now it came to pass on the day that the Lord spoke to Moses in the
>   land of Egypt, <-- [Sheini ends here]

Rashi also notes:

> [This is] connected with the following verse: [“That the Lord spoke to
>   Moses”].

Is there a special reason here why Sheini ends so abruptly....

or are there many cases where this happens -

(which would possibly mean that the separation of the portions does not necessarily denote the 'end' of a topic and the start of a new one)

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15454/why-does-the-second-aliya-of-vayeira-start-with-the-last-verse-of-one-topic-and

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Kli Yakar](http://www.sefaria.org/Kli_Yakar_on_Exodus.6.28) says that it is to emphasize that the verse stands alone - it is telling us that Hashem spoke to Moshe by day, and not at night, unlike all the other prophets.

Answer (score 5):

The Ibn Ezra says he is surprised at why there is a new paragraph here. He doesn't answer his question, but he says the one who divided the sections must have had a good reason, because he is much smarter than we are.